# jQuery fire function after another script is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a typing animation plugin that takes several second to run. At the very and a button is displayed. I also have a function for smooth scrolling to an anchor link and stripping the anchor from the URL. I load they typing script on document ready, and the scrolling function on window load. The problem I am having is that the scrolling function is not being fired when clicking on the anchor link in the typing plugin. I also tried calling the scrolling function imediately after the typing plugin. My code currently looks like this.

```
function anchorLinks() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top -1
          }, 500);
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
}; 


$(window).load(function(){
  anchorLinks();
});
```

and then...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#msg').typeIt({
      speed: 50,
      breakLines: false,
      autoStart: false,
      cursor: false,
      startDelay: 2000
  })
  .tiType('Hi!')
  .tiPause(1500)
  .tiDelete()
  .tiType('I\'m Sandra Willford, and welcome to TENDesign.')
  .tiPause(1500)
  .tiDelete()
  .tiType('Looking for a designer that has bright ideas for your brand?')
  .tiPause(1500)
  .tiDelete()
  .tiType('Well congratulations, you\'ve landed in the right spot :)')
  .tiPause(1500)
  .tiDelete()
  .tiType('I specialize in fresh and innovative digital, website & branding designs.')
  .tiPause(1500)
  .tiDelete()
  .tiType('Are you ready to take your brand to the next level?')
  .tiPause(1500)
  .tiDelete()
  .tiType('<a href="#start">OMG, Yes I am!...Show me more.</a>');
  anchorLinks();
});
```

suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what you want is to scroll to the top of  the page after a user clicks the button rendered at the end of the dialog you display? Also, could you explain what you think `scrollTop() ` does, and what you need it to do?

Comment: First of all this is surely can make problems: `function scrollTop() {
  $(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {` Remove the `  $(function() {` and its and `}`. And do not bint an event in a function. And instead `return false;` use `e.preventDefault`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this. Not tested:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href*=#]:not([href=#])', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //<!-- use this instead return false. 
    //Return false is triggering preventDefault and stopPropagation also.
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 1
            }, 500);
        }
    }
});
```

- You no need to call the function from your code, since, I removed it.
- Use `$(document).on()` for elements what loaded dynamically.
- Do not use `document.ready` inside the function.
- Do not attach event handler inside of the function if it is really not necessearry. Instead of this, use `off()` where is need.

Comment: thank you for that, as well as the code comments explaining why it works! Definitely learned something new!